# How to display value fetched from database?

Tags: ios, firebase, swiftui

I’m developing an iOS application with SwiftUI, and I’m having trouble displaying my data fetched from database.

#### Code

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

var ref = Database.database().reference()

class Observe {
    static func currentSingleEventObserve(completion: @escaping ((String?) -> ())) {
        let path = "supersonic/current"
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child(path)
        _ = ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            let temp = (snapshot.value! as AnyObject).description
            completion(temp)
        })
    }
}

struct CurrentDistance: View {
    var value: NSDictionary?
    var refHandle: UInt = 0

    @State var distance: String

    init() {
        Observe.currentSingleEventObserve(completion: { temp in
            self.distance = temp    // I want to mutate self.distance here
        })
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Distance")
            Text(self.distance)
        }
    }
}

struct CurrentDistance_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CurrentDistance()
    }
}
```

#### Database

```
|-supersonic
    |- current: 30
```

#### Problem

I want to mutate `self.distance` in the initializer. Trying to mutate `self.distance` in the closure I got an error `Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter`, and I don't know how to update the value. 
How can I display the value fetched from the database?

Comment: you should show your code first what have you try? otherwise go to firebase doc there are examples in swift

Comment: I tried to. sorry for not showing my code first.

Comment: What you're trying to return in the var body property isn't a View. Not sure what you're attempting there so maybe if you can clarify the question we may be able to help. Also, Firebase is asynchronous so data is only valid in the closure following the firebase function - you can't really 'return' a value from that closure. You could leverage a completion handler however.

Comment: I changed my code with your advice and could fetch data from database. But I still don't know how to display it.  @Jay

Comment: Ok. Firebase values are only valid within the closure following the firebase function. So if you want to display the firebase data, you would want to update the view's text within that closure. However, what is this *Observe.currentSingleEventObserve(completion:*? I can't find that function anywhere in the Firebase documentation. Please review the guide on asking questions: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I added the definition of the function in the code. I forgot to add it again after my browser crushed. I tried to update the view's text with value distance in my code, but failed. How to update it in that closure? @Jay

Comment: Also I'm thinking of using the value fetched from firebase as Integer. Is it possible? I added my Firebase database tree in the question.

Comment: Right here `self.distance = temp` is where you should update the UI. As in `self.my_ui_label.text = temp`

Comment: I still not sure how to update the UI. By my understanding I can't use ui_label with SwiftUI.. @Jay

Comment: I was using the label as an example as I don't know what element your updating. See my answer. Note it is very similar to yours, other than I am not using closures or any special classes. So my suggestion is to start with the code I presented, get it working, then you can add closures or whatever you want. The key is to ensure you're reading the data from Firebase successfully and your UI is updating properly first. Then you can customize your code further once you know the basics are in place and working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a somewhat generic answer as we are just going to be updating a UI element based on a value read from Firebase.

Firebase is asynchronous and values are only valid following the Firebase function, within the closure.

Suppose we have a simple SwiftUI app that displays a Text object, a button to click to load the data from Firebase, and then a var that holds what the text should be.

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @State var buttonText = "Initial Button Label"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(buttonText)

            Button(action: {
                self.readFirebase()
            }) {
                Text("Click Me!")
            }
        }
    }

    func readFirebase() {
        let ref = my_firebase_ref
        let textRef = ref.child("string_node")
        textRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            let myText = snapshot.value as? String ?? "No String"
            self.buttonText = myText
        })
    }
}
```

Here's my Firebase structure

```
root
   string_node: "Hello, World"
```

Comment: Trying this, I got error: Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter. How to fix it?

Comment: @rk-69 I don't have an escaping closure in my code so I am not sure. What line in my code is producing that error?

Comment: I still haven't tried your code but tried to use the method in my code and got that error. I'm not sure where to put `code to read data and update UI` and couldn't try. Where should I put it in the code? @Jay

Comment: @rk-69 I updated my answer with complete code. It sounds like you would benefit from the [tutorials Apple has for SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/SwiftUI/tutorials)
 - they are pretty good and worth the time to go through them.

Comment: I put that part into onAppear() method and succeeded displaying my value. But I still not sure how to observe the value change and display every time I update the value in the database.

Comment: @rk-69 If you want to observe the value change, then use .value or .childChanged with .observe instead of .observeSingleEvent. When when it changes, your text will be updated. See the Firebase documentation [Work with lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data) for observing changes in Firebase.

Comment: I went that tutorial through once... Maybe I have to review them.

Comment: It seems that your code require to tap the button to update the value. Is it possible to update the value automatically? @Jay

Comment: @rk-69 I think you missed my prior comment **If you want to observe the value change, then use .value or .childChanged with .observe instead of .observeSingleEvent. When it changes, your text will be updated.**. I put the button in this case because I am using .observeSingleEvent and if I change the data in my firebase, I would need to click the button to read the node again. You should read the Firebase documentation (see the link in my comment) to gain an understanding how firebase works.

Comment: Now I can do what I wanted to with your clear explanation. I really appreciate for teaching me of how to fix my problem. Thank you very much! @Jay